# Adding custom row number

Tags: mysql

I would like to add an auto row num into SQL statement instead of using the auto increment column as sometimes some record may be deleted and then the number in auto increment column is not continuously.

My SQL statement is

```
$sql = 'set @num=0; SELECT @num:= @num+1 as row_num, t.* FROM table_1 t;';
```

I query the statement using mysqli, $result = $db->query($sql);

I got error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @num:= @num+1 as row_num, t.* FROM table_1 t' at line 1", I can query this from phpMyAdmin without any problem, what is the problem to the statement when I query using mysqli?

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Comment: why not use something as `select * ,
@r := @r+1 as row_num
from table_1 t
cross join (select @r := 0) as t2` it will be a single query rather than in your case multi using `;` before the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_num, t.*
FROM table_1 AS t, (SELECT @row_num:=0) AS init
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using AS init ?

Comment: The "(SELECT @row_num:=0)" is a derived table that must have its own alias. The alias name doesn't matter, but its purpose is to init the row_num value, therefore the name "init".

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** what is the problem to the statement when I query using mysqli?

I suspect the problem is that you are attempting to execute two separate SQL statements within a single statement execution. (Based on the error message, it looks like MySQL read the SET statement just fine, but balked at everything that followed after the end of the first SET statement.)

(Note that some client interfaces do provide a way for connections to be configured to allow for "multiple statements" to be executed within the context of a single statement execution. But enabling that configuration throws open a wide door to some serious SQL injection vulnerability.)

---

And for the question you *didn't* ask i.e. "how can I workaround this problem?"...

As a workaround, you could initialize the MySQL user-defined variable using an inline view, for example:

```
SELECT @num := @num+1 as row_num
     , t.*
  FROM table_1 t
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @num := 0 ) i
```

We don't really care what the inline view (aliased as i) returns, except that we need it to return exactly one row, because of the JOIN operation. What we're really interested in is the side effect: the assignment of the value 0 to the user-defined variable `@num`.

This approach works because MySQL will process the inline view query and materialize the resultset (as a derived table), *before* the outer query runs.